# Can't inline a function?

Tags: delphi, inline

I declared a few functions only for legibility, and I want to check if the compiler is inlining them. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030801/7050476) I figured I could mark them `inline` and get a hint if they are not inlined, however, when I try to do so I get the following error:

```
[dcc32 Error] MyClass.pas(266): E1030 Invalid compiler directive: 'INLINE'
```

So I tried it with a simple function:

```
procedure TMyClass.Swap(var a, b : Integer); inline;
var
  c : Integer;
begin
  c := a;
  a := b;
  b := c;
end;
```

Alas, I get the same error. According to [the docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Calling_Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Using_the_inline_Directive) the default is `{$INLINE ON}`, so I assumed I only had to add `inline;`. Nevertheless I tried declaring `{$INLINE ON}`, to no avail. My Google-fu failed me, so here I am.

I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: You're supposed to put this directive only at the method declaration.

Comment: @Jerry, I don't know what it means. But it's an answer, actually. Short to be an answer post, but an answer :) I don't think you can refer to documentation here. Well yes, you can say that you can use that directive only at class method declaration, not at its implementation; and show a code example of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're putting it on the implementation, not the declaration. Putting it on the implementation will work for standalone functions and procedures, but not for class methods. Those must be defined as `inline` in the declaration itself.

```
interface

type
  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
    procedure Swap(var a, b: integer); inline;
  end;

implementation 

procedure TMyClass.Swap(var a, b:integer);
begin
  //
end;
```

Comment: Note that the `inline` directive *CAN* be applied to BOTH declarations AND definitions. Per the [*latest* documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Calling_Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Using_the_inline_Directive): "*The `inline` directive is used in function and procedure declarations **and definitions**, like other directives.*" They even provide example functions that are marked at both declaration and definition

Comment: @Remy, standalone functions and procedures can have this directive at declaration and implementation. Not class methods. Class methods can have it only at declaration (that's what documentation doesn't cover).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Sure, you can **also** repeat it to the implementation section if you'd like, but it's required at the declaration or it raises a compiler error (as the poster stated, and as I just tested in Berlin). (Not that it has much anyway, as the compiler will inline everything it thinks it can without the keyword, as long as the default `{$INLINE ON}` is in effect.)

Comment: @Ken, using `{$INLINE}` directive doesn't change anything. At method implementation you cannot use this directive. That's it.

Comment: @Victoria: Yes, that's what I've said (twice now, once in my answer, and again in my comment to Remy).

Comment: @Ken, sorry, I misread your comment (or it's been modified since then). Yet, I don't think it's a good way to link the documentation at this time as it considers only standalone functions and procedures, not methods.